# Undefined variable Laravel Foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to foreach some data but it says it doesn't know the variable:

The error I get:

```
    ErrorException in dbda158712a631f22ffd888cd244c74e60f3a433.php line 51:
Undefined variable: albums (View:        /var/www/clients/client2/web2/web/resources/views/album.blade.php)
```

Here is my code: 
**Album.blade.php**

```
@foreach($albums as $others)
    <option value="{{$others->id}}">{{$others->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

**My album controller function**

```
  public function getAlbum($id)
  {
    $album = Album::with('Photos')->find($id);
    return View::make('album')
    ->with('album',$album);
  }

  public function getList()
  {
    $albums = Album::with('Photos')->get();
    return View::make('index')
    ->with('albums',$albums);
  }
```

Comment: Use `@foreach($album as $others)`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois that gives me the following error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Post the **full** error message

Comment: what about return view('album', ['album' => $album]):

Comment: ErrorException in dbda158712a631f22ffd888cd244c74e60f3a433.php line 52:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/clients/client2/web2/web/resources/views/album.blade.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing album variable with view Album.blade.php, which is single object, not array of object so you can't iterate in a loop.

I think you are doing a mistake.

You want to do foreach in index.blade.php, because here you are passing the albums variable.

or

you need to return view album.blade.php in your getList function.

Comment: But I need the getList in my index aswell, is there a way I can return it in multiple views?

Comment: You want list in both blade file? if yes then you can't return two view in one function but you can pass multiple variable with a view

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code.

```
 public function getAlbum($id)
 {
      $albums=albums::with('Photos')->get();

       $album=albums::with('Photos')->find($id);

       return view('album',compact('albums','album'));

 }
```